# How to get input type string in calculation

Tags: javascript, html

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="prva">
<input type="text" id="brojOcena">
<input type="button" value="Izracunaj" onclick="Racunaj()">
```

JS

```
function Racunaj(){
  let prva = document.querySelector('#prva');
  let broj = parseInt(document.querySelector('#brojOcena'));
  broj = broj.value;
  prva = prva.value;
}
```

How can I get `let prva` as `prva = 15/broj` instead of "5+5+5" / broj

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is no division in your code, so what are you referring to? Please provide the code to *reproduce* the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Racunaj(){
  var prva = document.querySelector('#prva');
  var broj =document.querySelector('#brojOcena');
  prva.value = eval(parseInt(prva.value)) / parseInt(broj.value);
}
```

Use `parseInt()` to convert string to integer

And just you want answer like that

```
prva.value = eval(parseInt(prva.value)) / parseInt(broj.value);
//prva = 15/broj
```

`eval()` use to run string code know as integer add.

**Try This**